# Get the Role, Grade,School name of Logged in user from Google API

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-directory-api, google-classroom

I have integrated Google sign-in in our application, I need to check whether the logged in user is a teacher or student ,Organisation(school) name and Grade... Is there any API to get these details from Google and how to get the details form Google.

Answer (score 2):

- Regarding whether a user is a student or a teacher, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36427270/11543).
- It's not possible to determine the grade or school name via the Classroom API. (Please add a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) for this so we can judge whether it's something a lot of developers would find useful!)