# How can I distinguish between students and teachers?

Tags: google-classroom

Using the [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/) method [userProfile](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles), I can get various information about a user, including their name and email address, but not whether they are a student or teacher. How can I determine whether a user is a student or teacher?

Answer (score 2):

Classroom does have the concept of teachers and students, however **the distinction between teachers and students is only meaningful relative to a particular course** (it’s possible for a user to be a “teacher” of one course and a “student” of another) and so you might not be able to use these categories to apply access controls in the way you were expecting.

For example, if *alice@school.edu* is a member of a particular course’s [courses.teachers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.teachers) collection, and *bob@school.edu* is a member of [courses.students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students), then you can use this information to decide that *bob@school.edu* should not see certain content created by *alice@school.edu*. (For example, you might not want to show Bob the answers to a quiz that Alice has created on your website, just the questions.)

However, because by default *all* users can create courses, you probably do not want to show *alice@school.edu* sensitive information created by teachers of other courses, information intended for teachers that you provide (for example, if you are a textbook publisher), or giving her domain-wide admin features.

If you need to distinguish between “real-world” teachers and students, we recommend that you do this via a mechanism entirely separate from Classroom, such as checking that the user’s email address appears in:

- a separately-maintained list of teachers (e.g. CSV uploaded by admin)
- the classroom_teachers group – domain administrators can choose to [verify teachers](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6071551?hl=en) to allow them to create new classes (use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) to list a user’s groups)

Answer (score 0):

Classroom api dosent provide global role for a teacher or a student its vary from course to course so you can just call student/teacher [api](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list)
after that you will get json output and you find a special permission for teacher "Create Course" it will help you to recognized that the person is teacher.

```
"permissions": [
   {
       "permission": "CREATE_COURSE"
   }
]
```

in case of student this array will be null.